# Union not working in oracle

Tags: oracle10g

The below is the query am using to retrieve the records based on the certain conditions. When i use the query seperately, i get the result but when i add a union, its giving me the error as command not properly ended.

```
    select ltrim(rtrim(LV_ID)) || '|' ||  ltrim(rtrim(EXPS_TYP_CD)) || '|'
from sysadm.OM_CDM_PC_HNDSHAKE
where ltrim(rtrim(PROC_ID)) in 'B3_HNDSHK_OTC' and RUN_ID = 'ME-BD10'
and FISCAL_YEAR=2012 and ACCOUNTING_PERIOD=8 and BUS_DAY_NO=10
and ltrim(rtrim(LV_ID)) not in (' ','0','002','BEAD0')
order by ltrim(rtrim(LV_ID)) || '|' || ltrim(rtrim(EXPS_TYP_CD)) || '|'
union
select ltrim(rtrim(LV_ID)) || '|' ||  ltrim(rtrim(EXPS_TYP_CD)) || '|'
from sysadm.OM_CDM_PC_HNDSHAKE
where ltrim(rtrim(PROC_ID)) in 'B3_HNDSHK_OTC' and RUN_ID = 'ME-BD10'
and FISCAL_YEAR=2012 and ACCOUNTING_PERIOD=8 and BUS_DAY_NO=10
and ltrim(rtrim(LV_ID)) is null
order by ltrim(rtrim(LV_ID)) || '|' || ltrim(rtrim(EXPS_TYP_CD)) || '|'
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is with having the "order by" clauses on the two parts of the union.  Try removing those and see what you get.  If that gives you a result, you might then be able to add an order externally.

Or you might want to try rewriting your query to use an "or" instead of a "union".

Something like:

```
select ltrim(rtrim(LV_ID)) || '|' ||  ltrim(rtrim(EXPS_TYP_CD)) || '|'
   from sysadm.OM_CDM_PC_HNDSHAKE
where 
   (ltrim(rtrim(PROC_ID)) in 'B3_HNDSHK_OTC' and RUN_ID = 'ME-BD10'
     and FISCAL_YEAR=2012 and ACCOUNTING_PERIOD=8 and BUS_DAY_NO=10
     and ltrim(rtrim(LV_ID)) not in (' ','0','002','BEAD0')) 
   or
   (ltrim(rtrim(PROC_ID)) in 'B3_HNDSHK_OTC' and RUN_ID = 'ME-BD10'
     and FISCAL_YEAR=2012 and ACCOUNTING_PERIOD=8 and BUS_DAY_NO=10
     and ltrim(rtrim(LV_ID)) is null)
order by ltrim(rtrim(LV_ID)) || '|' || ltrim(rtrim(EXPS_TYP_CD)) || '|'
```

I unfortunately don't have an oracle instance to test this at the moment, but as you're selecting the same thing from the same table in both parts of the union you should be able to do it with an "or".